How to expose an grafana-alloy grpc service and test the connection to send traces
I want to create a grafana-alloy service, which receives traces via the jaeger protocol and by default the service exposes to port 14250. I have deployed the grafana-alloy service with its configuration in my kubernetes provider. I wanted to use this service to send traces from other components in other clusters to this, so I added an ingress on top of it with this config
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jaeger-receiver-ingress
  namespace: mimir-backend
  annotations:
  
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: <hostname>
      http:
        paths:
          - path:
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: grafana-alloy
                port:
                  number: 14250

But even after deploying it in ingress, I wanted to test the URL by using grpcurl, the url looked something like:
http:/// and it points to my grafana-alloy service
I am new to k8s and I am very confused on this part.
When I tried grpcurl, the error was "Failed to dial target host "hostname:14250": context deadline exceeded
How can I fix this issue?
This is my config.alloy file:
logging {
        level = "debug"
        format = "logfmt"
      }

      otelcol.receiver.jaeger "jaeger_port" {
      protocols {
        grpc { }
      }

      output {
        traces  = [otelcol.processor.resourcedetection.default.input]
        }
      }

      otelcol.processor.resourcedetection "default" {
        detectors = ["env", "system"]

        system {
          hostname_sources = ["os"]
        }

        output {
          traces  = [otelcol.processor.transform.drop_unneeded_resource_attributes.input]
          }
        }

      otelcol.processor.transform "drop_unneeded_resource_attributes" {
        error_mode = "ignore"

        trace_statements {
          context    = "resource"
          statements = [
            "delete_key(attributes, \"k8s.pod.start_time\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"os.description\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"os.type\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"process.command_args\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"process.executable.path\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"process.pid\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"process.runtime.description\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"process.runtime.name\")",
            "delete_key(attributes, \"process.runtime.version\")",
          ]
        }
        output {
          traces  = [
            otelcol.processor.batch.default.input,
          ]
        }
      }


      otelcol.processor.batch "default" {
        output {
          traces  = [otelcol.exporter.otlphttp.tempo_endpoint.input]
        }
      }

      otelcol.exporter.otlphttp "tempo_endpoint"{
        client {
            endpoint = "https://<tempo-endpoint>"
            auth = otelcol.auth.basic.grafana_cloud.handler
        }
      }

all the variables in <> brackets are secrets and are not templates that I am using in the config.

"Failed to dial target host "hostname:14250": context deadline exceeded " indicates a connection timeout issue. Try increasing the timeout configuration & make sure that hostname & portnumber are correct.
